# Python: how to install pymumps?

Tags: python

I am trying to use pymumps.

what i did:

i am following the instructions here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMUMPS

1- i installed mpi4py

2- i installed mumps library using (not required. this is mumps library)

```
apt-get instal libmumps-scotch-dev
```

3- i did settup of pymumps using:

```
python setup.py install
```

4- i put the folder mumps( which contained the installation) inside my project as shown below

[image]

so this should install pymumps locally. the folder mumps is as follows:

[image]

Now it is time to test it in the python interpreter

when i do

```
import mumps
```

i got this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "/opt/scripts/mumps/**init**.py", line 2, in 
    import _dmumps
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_dmumps'

Comment: Any specific reason to use this lib, compared to others, more recently updated? And what do you need it for?

Comment: if you mean : libmumps-scotch-dev, i have no problem in using others. if you mean other pymumps: can you give what other libs are available.

Comment: Visit github, search for mumps, filter by python. 3 libs. There is one more ,quite active, not found like this, but i can't remember the name. So what functionality do you need? Setting up mumps surely is not as easy as going for less-specialized options.

Comment: i need to use mumps library. inverse of large sparse matrix

Comment: (1) You should (almost) never inverse sparse-matrices. Always try to use the Ax=b approach (2) Without specifying the matrix, it's hard too chose a library (indefinite?, psd? symmetric? square?) (3) There is more than mumps. scipy's superlu is in many many cases a viable candidate, much easier to use and tested by many people. The differences in regards to mumps and superlu are mostly based on point 2.

Comment: i understand the math you are talking about. but i need to get the inverse, the entries in the inverse means somehting for me. it is square, unsymm, sparse. minimum 10000x10000. scipy libs are very slow for this size i tried them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160360/discussion-between-francois-saab-and-sascha).